# why my redux state not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutability, thunk

state not updating.when action is dispatched the state should update to isAuthenticated to true..but the state not updating..redux returning the initial state not the updated state.

```
export function setCurrentUser(user) {
      console.log(user);
      return {
        type: "SET_CURRENT_USER",
        user
      };
    }

   ...
    export function login(userData) {
      return dispatch => {
        return axios.post('/user/auth',userData).then((res) => {
          const { status, sessionId, username, error} = res.data;
          if(status === "success"){
            dispatch(setCurrentUser(sessionId));
          }else {
            dispatch(invalidUser(error));
          }
        });
      }
    }

//reducers

    import { SET_CURRENT_USER, INVALID_USER } from "../actions/types";
    import isEmpty from "lodash/isEmpty";

    const initialState = {
      isAuthenticated : false,
      user: {},
      error:{}
    };

    export default (state = initialState, action) => {
      switch(action.type){
        case SET_CURRENT_USER:
        return {
          ...state,
         isAuthenticated: !isEmpty(action.user),
         user:action.user
        }
        ...
        default: return state;
      }
    }
```

//component

```
onSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
      this.setState({ errors: {}, isLoading:true });
      this.props.login(this.state).then(
      (res) => {
        console.log(this.props.userData);
        if(this.props.userData.isAuthenticated)
          this.context.router.push("greet");
        },
```

(err) => this.setState({ errors: err.response.data, isLoading: false })
        );

```
  }
```

.....

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    userData: state.authReducers
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { login })(LoginForm);
```

Comment: where is your component code that updates it?

Comment: component added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not updating the payload data in your reducer

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
      switch(action.type){
        case SET_CURRENT_USER:
        return {...state, user: action.payload} //update user here
        }
        ...
        default: return state;
      }
    }
```

the above code uses es6 features and the assumption made is `isAuthenticated` and `error` are part of the initial state.

You are just returning the same JSON which is why your state is not updating.

Comment: return {
  14 |       ...state,
> 15 |       {user:action.user}
     |       ^
  16 |
  17 |     }
syntax error

Comment: can you elaborate ?

Comment: i tried to excute your code..but getting syntax error

Comment: where? which line? are you using es6, babel?

Comment: return {...state, **>{user: action.payload}**}
  //yes am using es6 babel

Comment: hey what is > doing there

Comment: Small typo in there, check now

Comment: console some value in switch case of SET_CURRENT_USER and check if you can see that

Comment: console not returning

Comment: If you are not seeing console then it seems reducers are not invocating.try debugging to find why it is happening

Comment: its working now
changed case set_current_user to **case "set_current_user"**
but i have a doubt why the first case didnt work ..i have imported the types too