# Redux State not Updating the first time

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

I know there are a lot of same questions posted in this site but none of them links to my issue. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39544713/why-my-redux-state-not-updating) is close to mine but I am not working with DB yet. Just a complete `react/redux` implementation.

I am implementing redux in my sample project for `reactstrap` `modal` and confuses me because one of my reducers not updating the state the first time. Consider my redux setup.

**Action**

```
export const showModal = (data) => {
   return {
    type: MODAL_TOOL,
    payload: data
  };
}
```

**Reducer**

```
 const initialState = {
     isOpen: false
 };
 export default function(state=initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case MODAL_TOOL:
            console.log(action.payload.isOpen); //logs true
            return {
                 ...state, 
                 isOpen: action.payload.isOpen
            }
        default: 
             return state;
   }
}
```

**Combine Reducer**

```
export default combineReducers({
    modal: modalReducer
});
```

**Component**

```
class TaskModel extends Component {
   state = {
       isOpen: this.props.modal.isOpen
   }
   onCreateTask = () => {
        this.props.showModal({
            isOpen: !this.props.modal.isOpen
        });

        this.setState({
            isOpen: this.props.modal.isOpen
        }); 
   }
   render() { 
       return(
          <Button
               size="sm"
               color="dark"
               style={{marginBottom: '2rem'}}
               onClick={this.onCreateTask}
           >
                Add Task
           </Button>
       )
   }       
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
     modal: state.modal
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { showModal })(TaskModel);
```

When I click the button `Add Task` the first time, it will not update the state even the log from reducer showing true. It works the 2nd time and update the `redux` `state`. My CRUD for the tasks is working fine with the same `redux` setup. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: How to you know the redux state is not updating the first time??

Comment: Why track whether it's open both in the state and in the store? Also, updating the Redux store, just like `setState()`, is asynchronous. So your `setState()` call which uses the store value `this.props.modal.isOpen` may not be using the correct value, since you call it synchronously after dispatching your action.

Comment: I wonder how its even updating the second time. `mapStateToProps` and `connect` need to be placed outside of the class.

Comment: @Fawaz, I update the component.

Comment: @pritesh, I am logging the state in the reducer so I know when I click the 2nd time it updates the state.

Comment: Doesn't matter if you are logging or not. Just keep `isOpen` in either redux or state. Not both places.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend To use `mapDispatchToProps` because this function is made to update redux store. You should call `onTodoClick` for instance like below in your click handler. And update the redux store. Now you will get 'toggleTodo' in your actions. Next is using `mapStateToProps` to get redux data. This is how it should work.

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onTodoClick: (isOpen) => {
      dispatch(toggleTodo(isOpen))
    }
  }
}
```

Here is some link to get more about the concept.

https://learn.co/lessons/map-dispatch-to-props-readme